# Where to find specific vintage rim/wheel?

Tags: wheels, rims, vintage

I have a 1983 Lotus Unique that came with 27 x 1" Ukai rims. The front wheel went missing and I'd like to find an original replacement. Lots of 27 x 1 1/4" or 1 1/8" out there, but I haven't been able to find 1" rims. Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: Ebay is probably your main option.   This is likely to be closed as a shopping question sorry.

Answer (score 2):

A web search for “bike rim nos ukai” has some hits, but they’re very expensive and steel, which is undesirable in a rim. If you’ve got a historically significant bike you were restoring, it might be worth it. Otherwise, I’d recommend against trying to match the original.